# Keep Percentage Formatting when exporting from SSRS to Excel

Tags: excel-2010, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that calculates the % of Revenue versus the total Contract Value for a job.  In SSRS I have it set to a percentage with 2 decimal points.  The format property is set to %0.00.  Now when I export to excel it looks great in all cases but one.  If the Revenue Amount is $0.00 and its divided by a Contract Value greater then $1 then the value is set to 0.0000000000000000 in Excel and not the 0.00% I expect.

How can I make it so it displays the expected 0.00%?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using **P2** in the **format** property?

The [Standard Numeric Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) tend to render better in Excel.

**UPDATE:**

I have recently had an issue where I was using `P1` for the format but the export would be 2 decimal places unless it rounded to 1.

The fix was to use `0.0%` for the format property instead of `P1`. Now all of the cells have the same formatting - even the zeroes.

Comment: If you still have problems displaying percentage or currency values on an iphone or ipad in the email excel preview app try to set the NumeralVariant value of the textboxes in the report definiton (2 works for most western cultures/languages). Works on SQL Server 2016 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

When creating Reporting Services (SSRS) reports, I have used FormatCurrency() and FormatPercent() around values to make the report look good. I learned that when you use those values, and export to Excel, you end up losing the ability to sum the values and what's on your SSRS report is much different on your Excel worksheet.  This is because everything is exported as text.

How to solve this. Remove all the FormatCurrency() and FormatPercent() functions.

On each of your fields, highlight them, then in the properties area, there is a “Format” property. I set that to C2 (C for Currency, 2 for the number of digits after the decimal, so if you wanted zero, it would be C0). Again for Percentages, same thing, highlight all the fields, and set “Format” to P2 (P for Percentage, 2 for the number of digits after the decimal).

Comment: @stylusnix - was this helpful to you?  Please mark as answered if so.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggested answer and it works great for currency. I wanted just plain decimals and ended up going with " #,0;(#,0);'' ". The final parameter makes zero values invisible. Of course, there are a ton of these formats.

[Text Box Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQaOq.jpg)

I got this by using the Number tab on the Text Box Properties dialogue box (right-click the text box and select Text Box Properties). Once I set it, I could return to the Properties window for the text box and see how that action got translated. Then I applied it to all the text boxes in the tablix.

Hope this helps.

[TextBox Properties Dialogue Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV8dM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this to eliminate the 0.000000000000000 export to Excel.  The field is otherwise formatted to a 2 decimal percentage.

=IIF(Fields!GrossMarginPctRelMonth1.Value = "0"
, ""
,Fields!GrossMarginPctRelMonth1.Value
)